# C compiler complaining about void (*)

Tags: c

My professor defined this in the .h file

```
void list_map(INTLIST* list, void (*f)(void *)); /*Applies a function to each element of the list */
```

I wrote the function like this:

```
 void list_map(INTLIST* list, void (*f)(void *))
  {
   INTLIST* pTemp=NULL;

   if (list == NULL)
    {
      //list is empty
    }
   else
      {
       for(pTemp=list; pTemp->next!=NULL; pTemp=pTemp->next)
          {
             f(pTemp); //f is a function pointer we call list map from main like list_map(lst, list_sort)
          }    
      }
  }
```

I call it in main like this:

```
  list_map(aList[i], (void*)list_sort);
```

In windows environment, no complaints, but I have to run this in a Linux environment. I'm using a makefile to compile all of the code and I get this warning and error:

*c++ -O2 -c main.c
main.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.c:53: warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
main.c:123: error: invalid conversion from ‘void (*)(INTLIST*)’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’
main.c:123: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘void list_map(INTLIST*, void (*)(void*))’
make: *** [main.o] Error 1*

Can somebody help with the error first and then maybe with the warning?

**Edit Portion:**

Someone asked for the list_sort function, here it is:

```
 void list_sort(INTLIST* list)
 {
  INTLIST* pTemp=NULL;
  INTLIST* pTemp2=NULL;

  pTemp=list;          //temp pointers to compare node values
  pTemp2=list;

  if (pTemp->next !=NULL)     //move to second node
   {
      pTemp2=pTemp2->next;
   }

  while(pTemp2 != NULL)
   {   
       //we implement a selection sort 
       //check if incoming node->datum with each node in the list
       //swap values if <
      if (pTemp2->datum < pTemp->datum)
         {
         //swap the values
         int temp = pTemp->datum;
         pTemp->datum = pTemp2->datum;
         pTemp2->datum = temp;
         }
         //advance the pointer
      pTemp2=pTemp2->next;
   }
 }
```

Comment: What does `list_sort` look like?

Comment: Can you change the list_sort function, or is that also fixed by the prof?  If it is fixed, seems like you have been dealt a tough hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:  *why are you compiling C code as C++?*.  Please compile it with a C compiler.

The prototype of `list_sort()` is:

```
void list_sort(INTLIST* list);
```

and `list_map()` has the prototype:

```
void list_map(INTLIST* list, void (*f)(void *));
```

This means that the second argument to `list_map()` is a function that takes a `void *` argument, and returns `void` (nothing).

Now, the C standard guarantees that a conversion of any object pointer to `void *` and back is OK, so given:

```
INTLIST *l;
/* make l point to a valid INTLIST */
void *pl = l;
```

this is OK:

```
list_sort(pl);
```

Note that, `list_sort()` could have been declared as:

```
void list_sort_generic(void *l);
```

In fact, since your professor is using `void *` in some places, he wants to extend your lists to be of a generic type at some point.

Anyway, you can pass an `INTLIST *` to `list_sort()` or `list_sort_generic()`, but `list_sort_generic()` can be passed any object pointer, whereas `list_sort()` can only be passed `INTLIST *` (or a `void *` which was converted from an `INTLIST *`).

Even though `list_sort()` can take a `void *`, the signature of `list_sort()` is not:

```
void list_sort(void *l);
```

So, the function types of `list_sort()` and `list_sort_generic()` are not the same, and cannot be interchanged.  `list_map()` expects a function of the kind that `list_sort_generic()` is, but is getting a function of a different kind.

Since you can't change any prototypes, you need a cast.  Now, `void *` is a generic type in C, so you would think such a cast would work.  But, as I said before, only object pointers can be converted to `void *` and back portably—not function pointer type.  So, you need to cast `list_sort()` to the correct type when calling `list_map()`.

That correct type is `void (*)(void *)`.  This is a function returning `void` and taking a `void *`.

Hence, the call should be:

```
list_map(aList[i], (void (*)(void *))list_sort);
```

But, since the type of `list_sort()` and the type expected by `list_map()` for its second parameter are not the same, the cast may or may not work.  Your professor has given you "not-so-nice" (i.e., *wrong*) prototypes.  Either he should have gone all the way in declaring type-generic functions, or he should have kept everything `INTLIST *`.  By going half-way, he has introduced a complicated cast that shouldn't have been there, and may not work.  I am sure if you bring this to your professor's attention, he will admit this oversight.

Hope that helped.

Comment: These are the things I am looking for very well written details, I could care less about the answer I am looking to understand the problem to fully utilize and learn the language.  Alok +1 plus accept for this thorough answer.  You could write a book and I'd buy it.

Answer (score 2):

And if you cast your callback to the proper function type?

```
list_map(aList[i], (void (*)(void*))list_sort);
```

Comment: "If what you get is not a duck, punch it until you get what you want" - I am sorry but this is a bad answer to give to a beginner...

Comment: @LiraNuna: It's a homework and he can't change the prototype of list_map. I'm afraid his teacher wants him to punch it until it quacks like a duck.

Comment: this will make the warning go away, but now it'll invoke undefined behaviour when the function gets called within `list_map()`

Answer (score 2):

Well,

```
void list_sort(INTLIST* list)
```

has the wrong signature to be passed as the second argument of

```
void list_map(INTLIST* list, void (*f)(void *))
```

Comment: Been trying to follow this stuff as I too am learning C...but I guess my question is it looks like list_map's void (*f) )(void*) is that just a function pointer?  What could he change void list_sort to become?  void list_sort(void* list) ?

Answer (score 2):

A simple cast of `list_sort()` is enough to make the warning go away, but it's not enough to make it actually work:

The C-standard doesn't guarantee that an `INTLIST *` and a `void *` have compatible representations, ie `void (INTLIST *)` and `void (void *)` are distinct, incompatible types. When `list_map()` invokes `list_sort()` through your `void (*f)(void *)` argument, C99 section 6.3.2.3, §8 applies:

> If a converted pointer is used to call
>   a function whose type is not
>   compatible with the pointed-to type,
>   the behavior is undefined.

To make it standard compliant, you have to write a wrapper function for `list_sort()`:

```
void list_sort_wrapper(void *list)
{
    list_sort(list);
}
```

and use that as argument to your call:

```
list_map(aList[i], list_sort_wrapper);
```

Also, if `list_sort()` is implemented correctly (didn't check the algorithm), it already walks the list, ie invoking it for each node doesn't make any sense at all.

**edit:**

Ok, `list_sort()` doesn't actually sort the whole list - that can be achieved via

```
list_map(list, list_sort_wrapper);
```

The naming scheme is a serious WTF - if the function doesn't sort the list, call it `list_sort_step()` or `list_select_head()` or something, but please not `list_sort()`.

Comment: list_map was a mapping function that takes a function pointer to list_sort() so as long as you call list_map you end up sorting the entire list, even though list_sort is doing this element by element.  I know it looks strange, but professors are strange people who really can't code.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `list_sort`, the parameter is `INTLIST *list`.

```
list_map(aList[i], (void*)list_sort);
```

By looking at the header, the function prototype is a function pointer that has a parameter which is of type `void *`

```
void list_map(INTLIST* list, void (*f)(void *))
                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

The function pointer `*f` has to match up the signature, hence the conflict and the warning generated by your compiler. Since `*f` points to the `list_sort`, the method signature does not match up.

It would work if your function prototype has this instead

```
void list_map(INTLIST* list, void (*f)(INTLIST *))
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Cannot change the list_map prototype that was defined by the professor and we are not allowed to change those prototypes.